# Upgrading PEAR on x86_64 GNU/Linux

Tags: php, linux, phpunit, pear

When I run `sudo pear upgrade pear`, it ends with the following error:

```
ERROR: unable to unpack /tmp/tmpsozA4Q/Structures_Graph-1.0.4.tgz
```

Has anyone run into something like this before and do you have any suggestions on how to resolve this issue? It's been keeping me up all night.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually this error arises due to a **very** outdated pear version that can't even talk to the pear server anymore and downloads a HTML page instead of the real archive.

To fix this you need to update pear by hand.

```
wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar 
php go-pear.phar
```

And follow the **"system install"** instructions.

---

Apart from that

```
unable to unpack
```

could mean that you don't have the ability to extract gzip archives or that the `/tmp/` disk is full or something related. It's not all that likely but in those cases:

```
pear install -Z pear
```

will download the .tar and not the .tgz

---

Comment: Thank you, you are beautiful! It turns out I was using PEAR version 1.4.9, and updating PEAR like you suggested worked perfectly, thanks again!